# Error: object not found in R. Headers not naming from .csv file

Tags: r, csv

I am new to R and I keep getting inconsistent results with trying to display a column of data from a csv. I am able to import the csv into R without issue, but I can't call out the individual columns.

Here's my code:

```
setwd('mypath')
cdata <- read.csv(file="cendata.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",")
cdata
```

This prints out the following:

```
   year       pop
1  2010 2,775,332
2  2011 2,814,384
3  2012 2,853,375
4  2013 2,897,640
5  2014 2,936,879
6  2015 2,981,835
7  2016 3,041,868
8  2017 3,101,042
9  2018 3,153,550
10 2019 3,205,958
```

When I try to plot the following, the columns cannot be found.

```
plot(pop,year)
```

> Error: object 'pop' not found

I even checked if the column names existed, and only data shows up.

```
ls()
[1] "data"
```

I can manually enter the data and label them "pop" and "year" but that kind of defeats the point of importing the csv.

Is there a way to label each header as an object?

Answer (score 0):

`year` and `pop` are not independent objects. You need to refer them as part of the dataframe you have imported. Also you might need to remove `","` from the numbers to turn them to numeric before plotting. Try :

```
cdata$pop <- as.numeric(gsub(',', '', cdata$pop))
plot(cdata$year, cdata$pop)
```